# Criar looping de execução até um elemento ficar visível

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

Preciso fazer um looping em que o mesmo pare de executar apenas quando um elemento específico ficar visível.
Ele deve clicar no botão filtrar e verificar se o elemento está visível, se o retorno for falso, ele executa novamente o processo. Se o retorno for verdadeiro, ele vai entrar no IF que eu vou criar.
Não sei se preciso usar o while com um for ou outra função...

Segue o código que tenho neste momento.

```java
//CLICA EM FILTRAR E ESPERA O STATUS FINALIZADO COM SUCESSO
        dsl.clicarBotao("ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_btnFiltrar");
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        String statusAssincProcess = "Iniciado";
        String statusAssincProcess2 = "Sucesso";

        while ("Iniciado".equals(statusAssincProcess) || "Sucesso".equals(statusAssincProcess2)){
            Thread.sleep(2500);
            dsl.clicarBotao("ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_btnFiltrar");
            Thread.sleep(1500);

            statusAssincProcess = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbStatus\"]"));
            statusAssincProcess2 = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbFinalizadoComErro\"]"));

            if ("Finalizado".equals(statusAssincProcess) || "Erro".equals(statusAssincProcess2)) {
                    Screenshot.tirar(navegador, "C:\\Users\\servflex050\\Documents\\TST_FATL\\printscreen\\"
                            + nomeTeste + "_" + Generator.dataHoraparaArquivo() + ".png");
                statusAssincProcess = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                        "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbStatus\"]"));
                statusAssincProcess2 = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                        "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbFinalizadoComErro\"]"));
            }
            if ("Finalizado".equals(statusAssincProcess) || "Sucesso".equals(statusAssincProcess2)){

                Screenshot.tirar(navegador, "C:\\Users\\servflex050\\Documents\\TST_FATL\\printscreen\\"
                        + nomeTeste + "_" + Generator.dataHoraparaArquivo() + ".png");
                statusAssincProcess = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                        "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbStatus\"]"));
                statusAssincProcess2 = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                        "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbFinalizadoComErro\"]"));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver a parte do loop para verificar o elemento na página com este código.

```java
        //VERIFICA SE EXISTE PROCESSOS ASSINCRONOS NA GRID
        String statusAssincProcess;
        String statusAssincProcess2;

        while (true) {
            WebElement grid;
            try {
                dsl.clicarBotao("ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_btnFiltrar");
                grid = navegador.findElement(By.id(
                        "ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_btnDownloadCSV"));
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                continue;
            }
            if (grid.isDisplayed()) {
                break;
            }
        }

        //VERIFICA STATUS PROCESSO ASSINCRONO - CREDITOS AO SPENCER
        do {
            statusAssincProcess = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbStatus\"]"));
            statusAssincProcess2 = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                    "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbFinalizadoComErro\"]"));

            if ("Finalizado".equals(statusAssincProcess) && "Erro".equals(statusAssincProcess2)
                    || "Sucesso".equals(statusAssincProcess2)) {
                Screenshot.tirar(navegador, "C:\\Users\\servflex050\\Documents\\TST_FATL\\printscreen\\"
                        + nomeTeste + "_" + Generator.dataHoraparaArquivo() + ".png");
                statusAssincProcess = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                        "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbStatus\"]"));
                statusAssincProcess2 = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath(
                        "//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbFinalizadoComErro\"]"));
            }
        } while("Iniciado".equals(statusAssincProcess) && "Sucesso".equals(statusAssincProcess2));
        System.out.print("Processo de " + nomeTeste + statusAssincProcess + " com " + statusAssincProcess2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parar de executar APENAS quando achar pode te levar pra um código rodando infinitamente, aconselho a colocar um tempo limite.

Agora sobre sua pergunta, pelo meu entendimento do que você quer fazer, um `do while` é mais que o suficiente, e seu código esta muito redundante em suas ações ao que parece, seu código faz isso:

```
clica no botao
espera 1.5 segundos
atribui o status1
atribui o status2

enquanto status1 == 'iniciado' OU status2 == 'sucesso' // Essa logica não faz sentido com o que você quer, você quer que espere enquanto NÃO for finalizado com sucesso, o problema é que se ele for finalizado com sucesso ele vai continuar executando isso aqui, pois finalizado com sucesso vai dar true no status2.

    espera 2.5 segundos //esperando porque? você não teve ação desde a ultima espera, e você não precisa ficar esperando por tempo fixo assim!
    clica no botao novamente //você não fez nada com o ultimo estado, porque ta clicando novamente ?
    pega o status1 da tela
    pega o status2 da tela

    se status1 == 'finalizado' OU status2 == 'erro'
        tira um print
        pega o status1 da tela //porque pegar de novo se você acabou de pegar?
        pega o status2 da tela //porque pegar de novo se você acabou de pegar?

    se status1 == 'finalizado' OU status == 'sucesso' //não é só jogar o 'OU status == sucesso' no 'se' de cima?
        tira um print          //print redundante
        pega o status1 da tela //porque pegar de novo se você acabou de pegar?
        pega o status2 da tela //porque pegar de novo se você acabou de pegar?
```

No meu entendimento faria mais sentido assim:

```
cria o status1
cria o status2

faca
    clica no botao
    pega o status1 da tela
    pega o status2 da tela

    se status1 == 'finalizado' OU status2 == 'erro' OU status2 == 'sucesso'
        tira um print
enquanto status1 = 'iniciado' E status2 = 'sucesso'
```

Resultado em java:

```
String statusAssincProcess;
String statusAssincProcess2;

do{
    dsl.clicarBotao("ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_btnFiltrar");
    statusAssincProcess = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbStatus\"]"));
    statusAssincProcess2 = dsl.obterTexto(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_grdServiceStatus_ctl00_ctl04_lbFinalizadoComErro\"]"));

    if ("Finalizado".equals(statusAssincProcess) || "Erro".equals(statusAssincProcess2) || "Sucesso".equals(statusAssincProcess2)) {
        Screenshot.tirar(navegador, "C:\\Users\\servflex050\\Documents\\TST_FATL\\printscreen\\" + nomeTeste + "_" + Generator.dataHoraparaArquivo() + ".png");
    }

} while("Iniciado".equals(statusAssincProcess) && "Sucesso".equals(statusAssincProcess2));
```

*Já que você tem o `dsl` ( ao que me parece esse dsl seria um page object certo? ) no meio do caminho ele DEVE esperar a disponibilidade dos elementos, você não deve sair socando Thread.sleep() pra la e pra cá.*

Caso o elemento esteja "sempre" na DOM:

```java
public String obterTexto(By locator) {
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
  return element.getText()
}
```

E caso o elemento demore pra ser ADICIONADO na DOM, você pode usar esse aqui:

```java
public String obterTexto(By locator) {
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
    .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
  return element.getText()
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pelos comentários, só assim percebi como meu código estava poluído. Agora está muito melhor! 
Não consegui explicar direito o que preciso, mas acho que vai ficar mais fácil de compreender.
E insiro os dados nos filtros na tela e clico no botão "filtrar" pra mostrar uma grid com os processos e seus status.
Para que a grid apareça, é preciso que rode um processo interno no servidor que pode demorar até 3 minutos, por isso preciso que em primeiro lugar, apareça a grid na tela.
Após isso eu faço toda essa verificação de status.
Acho que agora ficou mais claro.

Comment: O grid aparece com o status1 "iniciado" e status2 "sucesso". Após finalizado eles são alterados para status1 "finalizado" e status2 "sucesso" ou "erro".
Então a execução dos status serão feitas até eles serem diferentes de "iniciado" e "sucesso".

Comment: Certo, com o código que passei a cima, acredito que você consegue atingir seu objetivo, você popula os campos e depois executa aquelas linhas de código, isso deve cobrir seu objetivo, esse `do while`, no meu exemplo então ele ira parar de repetir assim que o status for finalizado + sucesso, porém não é o que você realmente quer, nesse caso você deve mudar a ultima linha para `while("iniciado".equals(statusAssincProcess) && "sucesso".equals(statusAssincProcess2));` irei editar a resposta pra cobrir isso.

Comment: E fique atento a uppercase ou lowercase.

Comment: Quando eu clicar em filtrar e a grid ainda não estiver disponível, não irá retornar o erro de execução ao tentar passar os status para as variáveis?

Comment: Editei o final da resposta e adicionei como deixar de usar o Thread.sleep, você deve fazer o uso de WebDriverWait na sua classe `dsl`.

Comment: O código resolve perfeitamente a tratativa dos status e o sleep, mas ainda não resolve a questão do elemento que preciso verificar. Eu preciso clicar em buscar(botão `id=xyz`) verificar se o elemento `id=abc` está visível na página. Se ele estiver visível, eu tenho um `true` e sigo com o script se o retorno for `false`, eu faço a execução de "clicar buscar", e "verificar elemento" novamente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98552/discussion-between-spencer-melo-and-allan-costa).